# Handle html without the use of TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser, ihtmldocument2

Hello everybody I am reformulating the question, I'm getting a html with a tidhttp and working this html in a TWebBrowser this way:

```
(WebBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument2).body.innerHTML := xHtml;
ovTable := WBT.OleObject.Document.all.tags('TABLE').item(1);
```

where ovTable is OleVariant;

more I want to do the same without having to use the TWebBrowser because it is consuming a lot of memory when created, I'm trying this:

```
  Idoc := CreateComObject(Class_HTMLDOcument) as IHTMLDocument2;
  try
    IDoc.designMode := 'on';
    while IDoc.readyState <> 'complete' do
      Application.ProcessMessages;
    v := VarArrayCreate([0, 0], VarVariant);
    v[0] := xHtml;
    IDoc.Write(PSafeArray(System.TVarData(v).VArray));
    IDoc.designMode := 'off';
  finally
    IDoc := nil;
  end;
```

Now, how do I get data from tables with the IDoc?

```
ovTable := Idoc.??
```

thanks!

Comment: What are you going to do with that table ?

Comment: I'm playing the data in this table in a StringGrid, and do not want to use the TWebBroser for this. I'm still not frazer, as you showed not work ...

Comment: There are plenty of third-party HTML parsers available.  Or, simply do you own substring searches for the specific HTML tags you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, how do I get data from tables with the IDoc?

`IDoc` is an `IHTMLDocument2` interface, same as `WebBrowser.Document` (it is just wrapped inside an `OleVariant`), so you can use similar searching code.  You just have to take into account that your `IDoc` approach is using **early binding** via static interface types at compile-time whereas your `TWebBrowser` approach is using **late binding** via `OleVariant` at run-time:

```
Idoc := CreateComObject(Class_HTMLDocument) as IHTMLDocument2;
try
  IDoc.designMode := 'on';
  while IDoc.readyState <> 'complete' do
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  v := VarArrayCreate([0, 0], varVariant);
  v[0] := xHtml;
  IDoc.Write(PSafeArray(System.TVarData(v).VArray));
  IDoc.designMode := 'off';
  ovTable := (IDoc.all.tags('TABLE') as IHTMLElementCollection).item(1, 0) as IHTMLTable; // <-- here
finally
  IDoc := nil;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

work this:

```
ovTable := (iDoc.all.tags('TABLE') as IHTMLElementCollection).item(1, 0);
```